# -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]:

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, crash, nsdictionary

HELP! I have been pulling my hair out with this problem for 1 hour now.

I am creating an Array in my .h file

```
    @interface LeftMenuViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITabBarControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) MKNetworkOperation *myNetworkOperation;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *listOfClubsArray;

@end
```

I am then pulling a list of items from an API call in JSON

```
///////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma mark Retreive List of Clubs / Teams
///////////////////////////////////////////

- (void)getListOfClubs {

    // Because we have a success from login auth we will now make a seperate call to gather club details

    self.myNetworkOperation = [app.teamManagerWrapper deviceID:@"adam" userToken:@"sdfdfgf" onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *result) {

        NSDictionary *data2 = [result objectForKey:@"data"];

        self.listOfClubsArray = [data2 objectForKey:@"user_clubs"];

        [self.tableView reloadData];

    } onError:^(NSError *error) {

        // error none

    }];
```

The JSON looks like this

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "data": {
        "user_clubs": {
            "5238": {
                "club_id": "45484",
                "name": "Testing This Club Name",
                "sport_id": "7",
                "primary_colour": "#000000",
                "secondary_colour": "#f15729",
                "members": null,
                "sections": {
                    "s": "Mens",
                    "j": "Junior",
                    "m": "Summer League",
                    "l": "Ladies"
                }
```

My tablecell looks like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ClubCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary *tempDictionary= [self.listOfClubsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];

    return cell;
}
```

It's crashing on this line

```
NSDictionary *tempDictionary= [self.listOfClubsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

With this Crash Log

```
2013-11-19 12:13:43.069 Manager App[11394:70b] -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8b0e9d0
2013-11-19 12:13:43.071 Manager App[11394:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8b0e9d0'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Any Help much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complementing the responses of colleagues:

If there is this option, you can simply produce correct JSON, using an array in user_clubs, like this:

```
{
"code": 200,
"data": {
    "user_clubs":[ {
        "5238": {
            "club_id": "45484",
            "name": "Testing This Club Name",
            "sport_id": "7",
            "primary_colour": "#000000",
            "secondary_colour": "#f15729",
            "members": null,
            "sections": {
                "s": "Mens",
                "j": "Junior",
                "m": "Summer League",
                "l": "Ladies"
            }
          ....
        ]
```

That way you have an array of dictionaries where the key in this case is 5238, which does not make much sense to me (should do to you), anyway my recommendation is to put this identificardor within the represented object and simply enumerate all objects in the array (the array is already ordered can also save a few steps), like this:

like this:

```
{
"code": 200,
"data": {
    "user_clubs":[ 
            {
            "user_id" = "5238",
            "club_id": "45484",
            "name": "Testing This Club Name",
            "sport_id": "7",
            "primary_colour": "#000000",
            "secondary_colour": "#f15729",
            "members": null,
            "sections": {
                "s": "Mens",
                "j": "Junior",
                "m": "Summer League",
                "l": "Ladies"
                     }
            }
          ....
        ]
```

That way you have an array of JSON objects (dictionaries) with known keys and easily operable.

Comment: I used this as my solution changing the JSON to an array! Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

In you JSON example there is not array of clubs but a dictionary, thus `objectAtIndex` will not work.

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "data": {
        "user_clubs": {
            "5238": {
            "club_id": "45484",
            "name": "Testing This Club Name",
```

Here you can see that data/user_clubs holds a dictionanry, if you want the `Testing This Club Name` you have use it key to grab it:

```
 NSDictionary *tempDictionary= [self.listOfClubsArray objectForKey:@"5238"];
```

Now that is not what you want, a solution could be to this:

```
NSArray *keys = [self.listOfClubsArray allKeys];
NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSDictionary *tempDictionary= [self.listOfClubsArray objectForKey:key];
```

But make sure that you then also tel the UITableView to correct number of keys and change

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *listOfClubsArray;
```

to

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *listOfClubsArray;
```

Comment: I think my head was in cloud 9, thanks for highlighting the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

JSon returning only dictionary but you are storing data in array. SO thats why is crashing. You need to change like that..

Try to make it NSMutableDictionary not array because in json there is no array.So you need to change it

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *listOfClubsDic;
```